# Content can not be resolved

Tags: java

While building package in eclipse:

```
  public static String getContents(File aFile)
  {
    contents = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try
    {
      input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
      String line = null;
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        contents.append(line);
      }
      return contents.toString();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
        if (input != null) {
          input.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

we are getting following three errors:

- contents can not be resolved (On line number 10)
- contents can not be resolved (On line number 12)
- contents can not be resolved to a variable (On line number 3)

We are using Eclipse Neon (4.6.0) and java jdk1.8.0_102

Already tried clean and refresh in Eclipse

Comment: All code in Java should be inside a class. On a side note, it is hard to find the lines based on line numbers, without seeing any

Comment: Now i have pasted complete class

Comment: No you have not, only the method...paste the ENTIRE class starting with 'public class...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define contents variable wrong. To define variable in Java you need to start with a type, then variable name and initializing expression (which is optional by the way).

So **contents** must be defined as follows:

```
StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
```

**Edit**

If you don't need synchronization support you should use **StringBuilder** class instead of **StringBuffer**

Comment: Ok tried, It says This method must return a result of type String                                                                                                   `public static String getContents(File aFile)`

Comment: You miss return statement in your method. It seems you need to add return contents.toString() at the end of the method

Comment: It is there just before first catch `contents.toSring();`

Comment: Method must return some value in any case. You add return statement in try block which means it will invoked when there no errors while you read the file. But if something goes wrong catch block will be invoked, and there no return statement here. I recomend you to write one return statement at the end of your method, and has one return statement in method. Your code will compile and become more readable